# Odoo13-CE: Module-E-mail-Marketing: Is it possible to add a new template (see the screenshot)?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

In Odoo13 CE (module-E-mail Marketing) there are only two default templates: 'Plain Text' and Template with different email components. Is it possible to add more templates (my own one - see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEvkt.png))?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Themes are defined inside [mass_mailing.email_designer_snippets](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/mass_mailing/views/snippets_themes.xml#L11) template, themes templates are defined inside [themes_templates](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/mass_mailing/views/themes_templates.xml) file.

To add a new theme:

- Define a theme template
- Alter the email designer snippets template and add a div inside it like for basic theme
- Add the images like `theme_imgs`, ... ( check `mass_mailing/static/src/img` folder)

***Example:***

```
<template id="email_designer_snippets_new_theme" inherit_id="mass_mailing.email_designer_snippets">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='email_designer_themes']">
        <div data-name="extended"
             data-nowrap="1"
             data-img="/MODULE_NAME/static/src/img/theme_imgs/extended_thumb"
             data-images-info='{"logo": {"format": "png"}}'>
             <t t-call="MODULE_NAME.theme_extended_template"/>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```